# How to Horizontal Autoscaler a Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, autoscaling

**EDIT:**

**SOLUTION:** I forgot to add `target_cpu_utilization_percentage` to `autoscaler.tf` file

---

I want a web-service in Python (or other language) running on Kubernetes but with auto scaling.

I created a `Deployment` and a `Horizontal Autoscaler` but is not working.

I'm using Terraform to configure Kubernetes.

I have this files:

**Deployments.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "rui-test" {
  metadata {
    name = "rui-test"
    labels {
      app  = "rui-test"
    }
  }
  spec {
    strategy = {
      type = "RollingUpdate"
      rolling_update = {
        max_unavailable = "26%" # This is not working
      }
    }
    selector = {
        match_labels = {
            app = "rui-test"
        }
    }
    template = {
      metadata = {
        labels = {
          app = "rui-test"
        }
      }
      spec = {
        container {
          name              = "python-test1"
          image             = "***************************"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Autoscaler.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler" "test-rui" {    
  metadata {
    name = "test-rui"
  }
  spec {
    max_replicas = 10 # THIS IS NOT WORKING
    min_replicas = 3  # THIS IS NOT WORKING

    scale_target_ref {
      kind = "Deployment"
      name = "test-rui" # Name of deployment
    }
  }
}
```

**Service.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "rui-test" {
  metadata {
    name = "rui-test"
    labels {
      app  = "rui-test"
    }
  }
  spec {
    selector {
      app  = "rui-test"
    }
    type = "LoadBalancer"  # Use 'cluster_ip = "None"' or 'type = "LoadBalancer"'
    port {
      name = "http"
      port = 8080
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `kubectl get hpa` I see this:

```
NAME       REFERENCE             TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
rui-test   Deployment/rui-test   <unknown>/80%   1         3         1          1h
```

Instead of:

```
rui-test   Deployment/rui-test   <unknown>/79%   3         10        1          1h
```

That is what I want.

But if I run `kubectl autoscale deployment rui-test --min=3 --max=10 --cpu-percent=81` I see this:

```
Error from server (AlreadyExists): horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "rui-test" already exists
```

In kubernetes appear this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server). Kubernetes needs to determine current CPU/Memory usage so that it can autoscale up and down.

One way to know if you have the metrics server installed is to run:

```
$ kubectl top node
$ kubectl top pod
```

Comment: I ran these commands and worked, then I guess that Google Cloud Platform already have a metrics server pre-installed

Answer (score 1):

The Horizontal Pod AutoScaler is dependent on resource limits being configured for your Deployment.

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work):

> Please note that if some of the pod’s containers do not have the relevant resource request set, CPU utilization for the pod will not be defined and the autoscaler will not take any action for that metric.

Comment: But Kubernetes in Google Cloud Platform does not already have this installed? I searched for documentation, and I thought that I don't need to configure more settings. If I need, I don't know where I need to change...

Comment: No, these are not set by default. Kubernetes does not know how much resources your application uses, but for the Pod AutoScaler to work, it needs to know when to scale, e.g. when is 70% of the CPU limit of the Pod reached. To set these constraints, check out the documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/. It should be easy enough to add a resources section to your Deployment.